# Angular FormArray ValidatorFn doesn't compile Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following Typescript errors with the below validator method. I feel, I have tried everything, and I am out of ideas. Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

The validator method doesn't let the project compile and the problem is thus unrelated to the use of the method.

```
Type '(formArray: FormArray) => { required: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
      Types of parameters 'formArray' and 'control' are incompatible.
        Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormArray': controls, at, push, insert, and 6 more.
```

```
public static minSelectedCheckboxes(min: number = 1): ValidatorFn {
    const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
   
      const totalSelected = formArray.controls
        // get a list of checkbox values (boolean)
        .map((control) => control.value)
        // total up the number of checked checkboxes
        .reduce((prev, next) => (next ? prev + next : prev), 0);

      // if the total is not greater than the minimum, return the error message
      return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
    };

    return validator;
  }
```

The method is taken from this example, which compiles, but it uses compilerOptions.strict = false, which is not acceptable.
https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Example in Stackblitz is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-98wn2v (fork of above example with compilerOptions.strict = true)

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Stackblitz is added to the question. It also fails in the example, if compilerOptions.strict are set to 'true'.

Comment: It's working as intended https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dokm2h

Comment: @Chellappanவ No, you haven't turned compilerOptions.strict to 'true' in that example. :-) It fails to compile, when it is changed.

Comment: Already enabled strict mode  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }

Comment: Those are Angular compiler options - not Typescript compiler options. If those are strict, the example fails. Look here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wwt4we?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts @Drag13 's answer solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValidatorFn` expects `AbstractControl` type as the first parameter, but you are passing `FormArray` which is the derived class.

This will work as expected:

```
function minSelectedCheckboxes(min = 1) {
  const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: AbstractControl) => {
    if (formArray instanceof FormArray) {
      const totalSelected = formArray.controls
        .map((control) => control.value)
        .reduce((prev, next) => (next ? prev + next : prev), 0);
      return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
    }

    throw new Error('formArray is not an instance of FormArray');
  };

  return validator;
}
```